# Laravel method in getCustomAttribute returning cullection null

Tags: laravel

I am trying to modify `$category->slug` by `getSlugAttribute()`. My `Category` class like this,

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function getSlugAttribute(){
        return $this->getRoute($this);
    }

    //Testing _____________________________________________________
    private $routes = [];

    public function getRoute(Category $category)
    {
        $this->determineCategoriesRoutes();
        return $this->routes[$category->id];
    }

    private function determineCategoriesRoutes()
    {
        $categories = $this->all()->keyBy('id');

        foreach ($categories as $id => $category) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($category, $categories);

            if (count($slugs) === 1) {
                $this->routes[$id] = '/' . $slugs[0];
            }
            else {
                $this->routes[$id] = '/' . implode('/', $slugs);
            }
        }
    }

    private function determineCategorySlugs(Category $category, Collection $categories, array $slugs = [])
    {
        array_unshift($slugs, $category->slug);

        if ($category->parent_id != 0) {
            $slugs = $this->determineCategorySlugs($categories[$category->parent_id], $categories, $slugs);
        }

        return $slugs;
    }

    //End Testing__________________________________________________

    //end of this class
}
```

Now when I request for `categories` it's just loading and giving me a blank page.

```php
Route::get('/test', function(App\Category $category){
   $categories = $category->all();
   return $categories;
});
```

This is my test route, also there is no error.

Comment: A blank page indicates a server error, could you check your server logs?

Comment: @MaartenDev , Oh really I didn't check it before, it's getting this error:  `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in C:\Users\Utpal Sarkar\Desktop\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 330`. But if I call `$this->getRoute($category)` in controller it's working fine (commented `public function getSlugAttribute(){
        return $this->getRoute($this);
    }`.

Comment: Please keep in mind that accessing the ->slug property on the `Category` model will call `determineCategoriesRoutes` and thus `->all()` on every call. If you had 100 Categories this would result in fetching 100 * 100 = 10000  Categories and thus exceeding the memory limits. Could you maybe look into refactoring the `determineCategoriesRoutes` by moving it outside the model and passing it as an argument?

Comment: @MaartenDev Please provide a good solution